# Python 3: How to add elements from list as values of a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with no values. The values I want to add are in a list.
How can I add the elements of the list as values of the dictionary?
The first element of the list has to be the first value in the dictionary and so on.

```
d = {2:'',3:'',4:'',5:''}

ll = [4,9,17,29]
```

Expected output:

```
{2:4,3:9,4:17,5:29}
```

Comment: Why was the question closed?

Comment: Because it doesn't fit the requirements of a Stack Overflow question. Refer to my [comment above](/questions/66226772/python-3-how-to-add-elements-from-list-as-values-of-a-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment117086139_66226772). In the future, please follow the [guidelines for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). We even have a useful [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) to  help you ask good questions.

Comment: I see, I think I should have added my approach and the output I got. Is that right? Or is there something else missing?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate both iterable at the same time.

```
d = {2: "", 3: "", 4: "", 5: ""}

ll = [4, 9, 17, 29]

for key, value in zip(d, ll):
    d[key] = value
```

**Output**:

```
{2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 17, 5: 29}
```